Asymptotics of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|\frac{x+\omega}{x-\omega}|)}{e^x +1} dx$ for $\omega \rightarrow 0$
I have the integral $I(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|\frac{x+\omega}{x-\omega}|)}{e^x +1} dx$, and want to obtain a good approximation for it as $\omega \rightarrow 0$.
Using desmos I obtained the approximation
$I(\omega) \approx -\omega\log(\omega)+0.874367\omega+0.071057{\omega}^3$ which seems to hold pretty well for $\omega<1$. But I can’t seem to figure out how to derive this. While the approximation for large $\omega$ is quite simple to determine via Taylor expansion, the same approach doesn’t seem to work here. I really can’t figure out a good approach, any help would be appreciated.

In the approximation formula, it is better to use $\omega$ instead of $x$, since the latter was the integration variable earlier.

@Gary I was on a mobile device and realized that right before posting--forgot to change it. sorry about that

In this answer, we obtain
$$ \bbox[padding:5px; border:1px solid navy; background-color:azure;]{ I(\omega) = -\omega \log \omega + \omega \left( 1 + \log(2\pi) \right)
+ 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right] } $$

Step 1 - Preliminary. We introduce some key identities. First, we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(at)\sin(bt)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\log\left| \frac{a+b + i\varepsilon}{a-b + i\varepsilon} \right|, \tag{1}\label{e:1} $$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Next, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{e^x + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt) e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(xt) e^{-nx} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t}{x^2 + n^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{t} - \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Finally, a similar computation shows that for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)} \sin(\omega t)e^{-\varepsilon t} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \operatorname{Im} \left[ \psi\left(\frac{\varepsilon+i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right],
\end{align*}
$$
where $\psi$ is the digamma function. When obtaining this equality, the series formula for $\psi$ is particularly useful.

Step 2. By Dominated Convergene Theorem and Fubini's Theorem,
$$
\begin{align*}
I(\omega)
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^x + 1} \log\left|\frac{x+\omega+i\varepsilon}{x-\omega+i\varepsilon}\right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^x + 1} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin(xt)\sin(\omega t)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin(xt)}{e^x + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\omega t)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t}\left( \frac{1}{t} - \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, let $J(\varepsilon)$ denote the integral in the last line. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
J'(\varepsilon)
&= -\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(\omega t)\left( \frac{1}{t} - \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)} \right)e^{-\varepsilon t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= -\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\varepsilon}\right) + \operatorname{Im} \left[ \psi\left(\frac{\varepsilon+i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right]
\end{align*}
$$
Using the boundary condition $J(\infty) = 0$, it follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
I(\omega)
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \left( -\int_{0}^{R} J(\varepsilon) \, \mathrm{d}\varepsilon \right) \\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \biggl( \int_{0}^{R} \arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\varepsilon}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\varepsilon \\
&\qquad 
- 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{R+i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right]
 + 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right] 
\biggr).
\end{align*}
$$
By the Stirling's approximation, we can check that
$$
- 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{R+i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right]
= -\omega \log R + \omega \log(2\pi) + \mathcal{O}(R^{-1}) $$
as $R \to \infty$. Plugging this back and substituting $\varepsilon = \omega x$,
$$
\begin{align*}
I(\omega)
&= \omega \lim_{R\to\infty} \biggl(
\int_{0}^{R/\omega} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
- \log R \biggr) \\
&\qquad 
+ \omega \log(2\pi)
+ 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right] \\
&= -\omega \log \omega + \omega \biggl(
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{\mathbf{1}[x \geq 1]}{x} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \\
&\qquad 
+ \omega \log(2\pi)
+ 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right] \\
&= \bbox[padding:5px; border:1px solid navy; background-color:azure;]{ -\omega \log \omega + \omega \left( 1 + \log(2\pi) \right)
+ 2\pi \operatorname{Im} \left[ \log\Gamma\left(\frac{i\omega}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \right] }
\end{align*}
$$
Using this, we can obtain the series expansion of $I(\omega)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
I(\omega)
&= -\omega \log \omega
+ \omega \left( 1 - \gamma + \log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \right)
+ \frac{7\zeta(3)}{12\pi^2} \omega^3
- \frac{31\zeta(5)}{80\pi^4} \omega^5
+ \frac{127\zeta(7)}{448\pi^6} \omega^6
- \cdots.
\end{align*}
$$

Addendum. Here we provide more details in some non-trivial steps in the above computation.

Lemma 1. Let $a > 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, as $ a \to \infty$,
$$ \operatorname{Im}\log\Gamma(a+ib) = b \log a + \mathcal{O}(a^{-1}). $$

Proof. By the Stirling's formula,
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Im}\log\Gamma(a+ib)
&= \operatorname{Im}\left[ (a + ib - \tfrac{1}{2})\log(a + ib) - (a + ib) + \tfrac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) + \mathcal{O}(a^{-1}) \right] \\
&= (a-\tfrac{1}{2})\arctan(b/a) + b\log\left|a + ib\right| - b + \mathcal{O}(a^{-1}) \\
&= b + b\log a - b + \mathcal{O}(a^{-1}) \\
&= b\log a + \mathcal{O}(a^{-1}).
\end{align*}
$$

Lemma 2. We have
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{\mathbf{1}[x \geq 1]}{x} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x = 1. $$

Proof. By substituting $x \mapsto 1/x$, it suffices to prove that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{\arctan x}{x^2} - \frac{\mathbf{1}[x \leq 1]}{x} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x = 1. $$
Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1 < R$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\varepsilon}^{R} \left[ \frac{\arctan x}{x^2} - \frac{\mathbf{1}[x \leq 1]}{x} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \left[ -\frac{\arctan x}{x} \right]_{\varepsilon}^{R}
+ \int_{\varepsilon}^{R} \frac{1}{x(x^2 + 1)} \, \mathrm{d}x
- \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{\arctan \varepsilon}{\varepsilon} - \frac{\arctan R}{R}
+ \int_{1}^{R} \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x 
- \int_{\varepsilon}^{R} \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{\arctan \varepsilon}{\varepsilon} - \frac{\arctan R}{R}
+ \log \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2 + 1}} + \log \sqrt{\varepsilon^2 + 1}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now letting $R \to \infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ proves the desired equality.

Lemma 3. For any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(at)\sin(bt)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\log\left| \frac{a+b + i\varepsilon}{a-b + i\varepsilon} \right|. $$

Proof. This is a Frullani's integral in disguise:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(at)\sin(bt)e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{[\cos(at-bt) - \cos(at+bt)]e^{-\varepsilon t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(\varepsilon-ia+ib) t} - e^{-(\varepsilon-ia-ib) t}}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-b}^{b} -i  e^{-(\varepsilon-ia-is) t} \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \int_{-b}^{b} \frac{-i}{\varepsilon-ia-is} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log \left| \frac{\varepsilon-ia-ib}{\varepsilon-ia+ib} \right|.
\end{align*}
$$
Now the desired identity follos by multiplying $i$ to both the numerator and denominator of the fraction inside the logarithm.

This is incredible, I've been looking at this integral for weeks and was thoroughly convinced even an ugly closed form did not exist. Thank you so much for this!

This is not a realy an answer only answer from Mathematica:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log \left(\left| \frac{x+\omega }{x-\omega }\right| \right)}{\exp (x)+1} \, dx\approx \omega -\gamma  \omega +\omega  \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\omega  \log (\omega )+\frac{7 \omega ^3 \zeta (3)}{12
   \pi ^2}-\frac{31 \omega ^5 \zeta (5)}{80 \pi ^4}+\frac{127 \omega ^7 \zeta (7)}{448 \pi ^6}$$
f[\[Omega]_] := \[Omega] - EulerGamma  \[Omega] + \[Omega]  Log[\[Pi]/
 2] - \[Omega]  Log[\[Omega]] + (7 \[Omega]^3 Zeta[3])/(
12 \[Pi]^2) - (31 \[Omega]^5 Zeta[5])/(80 \[Pi]^4) + (
127 \[Omega]^7 Zeta[7])/(448 \[Pi]^6);

g[\[Omega]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[Log[Abs[(x + \[Omega])/(x - \[Omega])]]/(
Exp[x] + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", 
WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 20];

N[f[1/10], 20] - g[1/10](*for: \[Omega]=1/10 *)

(* 2.341082*10^-14 *)

